Sign in not creating session initially. When the signin form creates a new user, everything works fine, except the session doesnt start on signup
I have a signin/sign up form using a react front end, sql and flask on the back.
Basically, the login and sign in both work fine. The session gets created and the logout works fine.
The issue is that the sign up form, the one that creates a new user that doesnt currently have loging capabilities, does everything  perfectly excpet creating the session immediately after signup.
The the user can sign up, create a new username, password, etc and immediately access the closed off routes, but the session is not created. However, if the user logs out and in again, the session/cookie will be created.
sign up route
class Signup(Resource):
    def post(self):
        form_json = request.get_json()
        username = form_json.get("username")
        email = form_json.get("email")
        password = form_json.get("password")

        # Check if all required fields are provided
        if not username or not email or not password:
            return make_response({"error": "All fields are required: username, email, password"}, 400)

        # Check if the username or email already exists
        if User.query.filter_by(username=username).first():
            return make_response({"error": "Username already taken"}, 400)
        if User.query.filter_by(email=email).first():
            return make_response({"error": "Email already registered"}, 400)

        try:
            new_user = User(username=username, email=email)
            new_user.password = password  # Use password setter for hashing
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()

            # Automatically sign in the new user
            session["user_id"] = new_user.id
            return make_response(new_user.to_dict(), 201)
        except Exception as e:
            return make_response({"error": str(e)}, 500)
        
api.add_resource(Signup, '/signup')

the usercontext on the front end that wraps the entire app:
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/check_session").then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then((user) => setUser(user));
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const checkSession = () => {
    return fetch("/check_session", { credentials: "include" }).then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json().then((user) => {
            setUser(user);
            return user;
          });
        } else {
          setUser(null);
          throw new Error("No active session");
        }
      }
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkSession().catch((error) =>
      console.log("No active session on load:", error)
    );
  }, []);

  const logInUser = (loginData) => {
    return fetch("/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
      credentials: "include",
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("Login failed");
      }
    });
  };

  const logOutUser = () => {
    return fetch("/logout", { method: "DELETE", credentials: "include" }).then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          setUser(null);
        } else {
          throw new Error("Logout failed");
        }
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{ user, setUser, logInUser, logOutUser, checkSession }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

When I create the new user to sign up, I want them to create a new user (which they can), log into the app(which they can) and the immediately have a session/cookie created. But that doesn't happen until they log in a second time.
